# Python socket with PACKET_MMAP

Tags: python, sockets, networking

Is there a PACKET_MMAP or similar flag for python sockets? I know in C one can use a zero-copy/circular buffer with the previous mention flag to avoid having to copy buffers from kernel space to user space but I cannot find anything similar in the python documentation.

Thanks for any input on docs or code to look into.

Answer (score 1):

So it looks like buffer or memoryview will do the trick. Although, there is some discrepancies in the sites I found regarding whether python 2.7 supported this or not, I will have to test it out to make sure